# Set $V_0=\{v \in V : hv=v , \forall h \in G\}$.Show that $V_0$ is a submodule of V.

Tags: representation-theory

Set $V_0=\{v \in V : hv=v ,\forall h \in G\}$.

**(a) Show that $V_0$ is a submodule of V. You may assume that V is a vector space. [4 marks]**

I thought I had done this previously, but now the question comes up on a past paper it is 4 marks and what I had I don't believe is worthy 4 marks so much be wrong.

We assume that V is a vector space so it remains to show that g.$v_0$ exists in $V_0$ for all g in G, $v_0$ in $V_0$.

Take $v_0$ in $V_0$ and g in G.
Then g.$v_0$=$v_0$ by the action defined in $V_0$, so $V_0$ is a submodule of V.

**(b) Show that the map $\phi=V -> V$ defined by $\phi(v)=∑gv$ for g in G, for all v in V is an FG homomorphism. You may assume it is linear. [4 marks]**

I have thoroughly confused myself with this part.

So I need to show that $\phi(k.v)=k.\phi(v)$, but every time I try to do so I get something different.

**c) Show that Im($\phi$)⊆$V_0$. If F is the complex numbers, show that Im($\phi$)=$V_0$**

I haven't tried this part yet, but I thought I would add it incase I need help later on, which I probably will.
Thanks

Comment: Re-write the expression $g\cdot(k\cdot v)$ in the form $k\cdot (k^{-1} g k)\cdot v$ and observe that for any fixed $k \in G$ the map $g \mapsto k^{-1}gk$ is a bijection of $G$ onto itself.